# MDX Query SUM PROD to do Weighted Average

Tags: mdx, olap, bids

I'm building a cube in MS BIDS. I need to create a calculated measure that returns the weighted-average of the rank value weighted by the number of searches. I want this value to be calculated at any level, no matter what dimensions have been applied to break-down the data.

I am trying to do something like the following:

I have one measure called [Rank Search Product] which I want to apply at the lowest level possible and then sum all values of it

```
IIf([Measures].[Searches] IS NOT NULL, [Measures].[Rank] * [Measures].[Searches], NULL)
```

And then my weighted average measure uses this:

```
IIf([Measures].[Rank Search Product] IS NOT NULL AND SUM([Measures].[Searches]) <> 0,
SUM([Measures].[Rank Search Product]) / SUM([Measures].[Searches]), 
NULL)
```

I'm totally new to writing MDX queries and so this is all very confusing to me. The calculation should be

```
 ([Rank][0]*[Searches][0] + [Rank][1]*[Searches][1] + [Rank][2]*[Searches][2] ...)
 / SUM([searches])
```

I've also tried to follow what is explained in this link http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/02/13/performance-of-aggregating-data-from-lower-levels-in-mdx.aspx

Currently loading my data into a pivot table in Excel is return #VALUE! for all calculations of my custom measures.

Please halp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you would need an intermediate measure, lets say `Rank times Searches`, in the cube. The most efficient way to implement this would be to calculate it when processing the measure group. You would extend your fact table by a column e. g. in a view or add a named calculation in the data source view. The SQL expression for this column would be something like `Searches * Rank`. In the cube definition, you would set the aggregation function of this measure to `Sum` and make it invisible. Then just define your weighted average as

```
[Measures].[Rank times Searches] / [Measures].[Searches]
```

or, to avoid irritating results for zero/null values of searches:

```
IIf([Measures].[Searches] <> 0, [Measures].[Rank times Searches] / [Measures].[Searches], NULL)
```

Since Analysis Services 2012 SP1, you can abbreviate the latter to

```
Divide([Measures].[Rank times Searches], [Measures].[Searches], NULL)
```

Then the MDX engine will apply everything automatically across all dimensions for you.

In the second expression, the `<> 0` test includes a `<> null` test, as in numerical contexts, NULL is evaluated as zero by MDX - in contrast to SQL.

Finally, as I interpret the link you have in your question, you could leave your measure `Rank times Searches` on SQL/Data Source View level to be anything, maybe just 0 or `null`, and would then add the following to your calculation script:

```
({[Measures].[Rank times Searches]}, Leaves()) = [Measures].[Rank] * [Measures].[Searches];
```

From my point of view, this solution is not as clear as to directly calculate the value as described above. I would also think it could be slower, at least if you use aggregations for some partitions in your cube.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried this but am still getting the same issue. I've updated my question to show what I am trying at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! adding a names calculation in the data source view was a great idea, I never thought of that. Works perfectly now thanks.